# Does durable Django atomic transaction imply we don't need savepoints

Tags: django, transactions

A Django atomic transaction has the `durable` and `savepoint` arguments. See [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/db/transactions/#django.db.transaction.atomic).

`durable=True` ensures the atomic block is the outermost atomic block. Per the docs:

> It is sometimes useful to ensure an atomic block is always the outermost atomic block, ensuring that any database changes are committed when the block is exited without errors. This is known as durability and can be achieved by setting durable=True

A PostgreSQL `SAVEPOINT` establishes a new savepoint within the current transaction. Sounds like this is only needed if the atomic block is nested.

I have the following questions:

- If `durable=True` then `savepoint` should ALWAYS be `False`, right? Because there's no point in using a savepoint if the atomic block is the outermost atomic block.
- If `durable=True`, should Django set `savepoint=False` for us? Reading through the source code, it doesn't appear to do it for us but I feel like it should.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `transaction.atomic(durable=True)` is nested in another `transaction.atomic` a `RuntimeError` will be thrown. I think you can't really have a situation when you could set `savepoint=False` and `durable=True` (other than outermost `transaction.atomic` in which case it won't be a savepoint in the first place).

[This blog post](https://seddonym.me/2020/11/19/trouble-atomic/) might be helpful.